# Does an open-source poker-related math library exist?

Tags: math, open-source, probability, poker

I would like to develop a poker odds application that can give the probability of various game situations. Since the application will be mostly statistical analysis, I figured I would see if someone else had already written a library that implements the required mathematics.

I would prefer cross-platform open-source in C++, but that's not a requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a subset of Dave's list, but I suggest you look at twodimes.net.  It is a web app that uses the **pokenum** open source library.  It is written in C.  It does hand enumeration and stats for several poker varieties.

http://twodimes.net/poker/info/

Comment: The libraries they use seem to be very complete and fairly mature. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](http://www.dmoz.org/Games/Gambling/Poker/Software_and_Tools/) a list of poker-related software tools.

Answer (score 1):

Complete source code for Texas hold'em poker game evaluator can be found here:

http://www.advancedmcode.org/poker-predictor.html

It is built for matlab, the GUI id m-coded but the computational engine is c++.

It allows for odds and probability calculation. It can deal, on my 2.4Ghz laptop, with a 100000 10 players game computation in 0,3 seconds.

An accurate real time computer:-)